# Refactoring ajax using twig

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twig

I'm trying to refactor a chained ajax call (way too chained) for a simpler way separating HTML, PHP and js using twig. 
i have something like:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json", 
    url: "{{ urlsf }}",// THIS WILL LOAD SOME DATA
    success: function (response) {
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: { per: response } ,
         url: 'renderPage.php',
         success: function (cont_contador) {
           $('#main_content').html(cont_contador);
         }//end of success
      });//end of ajax for render call
    }//end of success
  });//end of ajax that loads data
```

This same success->ajax call is repeated several times, but i think one is enough to make my point. 
The renderPage.php renders another file which had one js/jquery function and one div which uses the twig function, PLUS setting the response as a twig variable passing it to the render array.

I moved the  to the main library and the  to the main HTML structure (which has twig) while handling the load with my controller.

Now, this is where I'm having these troubles: 
I can't move the response to twig using javascript.
I can't replace the twig with the javascript response var because this twig variable is being used in other places of the code.
I don't want to keep the ajax call, in fact, I want to delete it to keep only the json call.

---

**edit**

I'll try to make a schema of what I'm looking for:

- *main controller*: loads php connections, sets security, sets main twig variables and renders the main template
- *main template*: loads CSS and js libraries including jquery and main js custom functions among those, contains HTML and twig block main structures using includes. Invokes the. ready
- *js functions*: contains the events and functions associated with the HTML

Actually there is a function triggered by one event that makes calls to API, returns data, then renders one part that triggers another event that renders another part, then triggers another ... which can be all triggered/loaded in one go, but at one of this renders it saves one twig variable used in other parts of the web. I want to have that twig variable started in some different way.

Comment: what is the url represented by {{ urlsf }}

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you would to avoid any ajax calls you would need to render everything in your main controller?

Comment: The url is an external api call which returns a json with the data needed.
And yes, the main controller renders a main twig template wich includes js and css libraries and other twig templates using blocks and so on

Comment: Isn't the twig variables loaded server side? And you trying to alter you template client side? Anyhow, can't you just replace the data with js?  But I guess I don't fully understand your question. What's the difference between "json call" and "ajax call"?

Comment: @Wimanicesir I said ajax call for generic, while json call is an ajax call wich only returns a json. I try to be as clear and neat as possible, but im glad to answer for clarification.
I am not changing the template but trying to alter and use its internal variables. And the twig calls are started here and used at other parts of the proyect i am not allowed to change.

Comment: But an ajax call cannot set/alter a `twig`-variable in your main template. That is what makes this question confusing.

Comment: this question isn't confusing, but it merely ignores the actual purpose of Twig. this almost certainly is a job for DOM manipulation on callback. and if you need to push whatever data trough a template engine, request server-side, not client-side.

Comment: But if another secondary yet empty template starts a twig variable (server side) by an independent call then its accessible through the main template maybe even changing what was there first. Or i am mislead?

Comment: The main template has no knowledge of any other template rendered by ajax, the template is already rendered and served as output (html) to the client

Comment: So let me see if i got this right. The last render on the ajax pile set a twig variable, but this variable would ONLY work for that piece of html right? In that case, can i assume it cannot be used outside this template (with the setted value) ?

Comment: Feel free to post your comments as answers, I would be more than happy to upvote your contribution. You indeed helped me understand twig better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, a small explanation of Twig:

Twig is a template processor. A template processor generates a HTML file from another file that contains HTML with added features such as:

- variables and functions
- text replacement
- file inclusion (or transclusion)
- conditional evaluation and loops

This process happens on **the server side**. The client side only gets a HTML result.
Client side languages, such as JS, can change this HTML directly but not the unrendered variables or loops. This is because JS never sees this logic.

With AJAX however you can still make server side code run. I would advise to initially set your twig variables **with a value in your database**. Whenever you change this record in you db, all templates will be updated.